# How to implement keyword "Unselect Frame" in Selenium 2?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to implement the keyword "Unselect Frame" with selenium-webdriver, but have no idea how to make it universal to all frames.

The following example doesn't work:

```
/**
 *  Sets the top frame as the current frame.
 * 
 */
public void unselectFrame(){

    try {
        WebElement element = getElement("//body");
        driver.switchTo().frame(element);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         //exception
    }
}
```

Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you mean switching out of the frame?
In that case this should work:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```